# DiscordJS - Connecting constants from other files

Tags: discord, discord.js

I made a verification command and now I'm changing it so it's multi-guilded. I have a 'createverify' command that's used to create the Verification Embed. It's a Slash Command.

```
const channel = interaction.options.getChannel('channel');
const nv = interaction.options.getRole('nonverified');
const v = interaction.options.getRole('verified');
const desc = interaction.options.getString('description');
```

These are the constants I pulled from the slash command in 'createverify.js'.

Now I have a seperate file which is used for when somebody clicks the verify button. Since it's in seperate file I have to connect the files.

```
const { v, nv } = require("../../Moderation/createverify");
```

I put this at the top of the second file, and then in the file, I defined **v** and **nv** like this:

```
const role = interaction.guild.roles.cache.get(v);
```

```
const roleremove = interaction.guild.roles.cache.get(nv);
```

The error I get is:

```
Error: Cannot find module '../../Moderation/createverify'
```

I don't know if the error is caused by me wrongly connecting the files or something else.

Comment: The file path you provided is invalid. What does your file structure look like?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/cym95vl   -  I'm connecting the createverify.js to interactionCreate.js

Comment: The Moderation folder is inside the Commands folder: `../../Commands/Moderation/createverify`

Comment: Oh, that works but at the start, I'm in the 'interactions' folder so the first .. puts me in Events and the second .. in Commands. Why do I have to specify Commands again?